# How to bridge 802.1X ethernet to wireless?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, openwrt

Problem: My high level goal is to have a device which would be connected to an 802.1X network over Ethernet and would act as a wireless router, offering WPA2-PSK wireless access to the wireless clients (with possible device MAC address filtering). This should authenticate to 802.1X and transparently send all packets. Correct me if I'm wrong, but 802.1X operates on IP level, right? That is, it's transparent to TCP/UDP and above levels.

Why? My university dorm only has an 802.1X Ethernet connection and I'd really like using wireless.

How? Upon some searching, I've found that using a router with custom firmware like OpenWrt or DD-WRT could work, however I have 0 networking experience (aside theoretical classes) and would appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this if you have a wireless router that can run an 802.1X supplicant on its WAN port, and that also does NAT so that its wireless clients' MAC addresses aren't exposed to the 802.1X-secured Ethernet network.

802.1X actually works at the Ethernet MAC layer, below IP. So yes, it's transparent to not only TCP/UDP, but to IP as well. But if you leave your "wireless router" in bridge mode, the client's traffic will cause 802.1X to lock out your Ethernet port. So you have to hide your clients behind a NAT gateway.

I can confirm that it's possible and shouldn't be too hard to do, but I haven't done it myself, so I can't provide a step-by-step configuration guide, if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bridge products as follows:
http://www.silexeurope.com/en/home/products/access-point-wireless-bridge/br-300an.html
http://www.silexeurope.com/en/home/products/access-point-wireless-bridge/br-310ac.html

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Can you include the relevant parts of the information in your answer? [Link-only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Thanks!

Comment: Kindly explain with details in order to help users